# UITableViewCell - how to reset content before reusing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

There's an annoying bug that I can't fix.

I have a `CustomCell`, and in it I have a subview that changes it's color according to object's value.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {        
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    MyObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([object.redColor isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]) {
        cell.colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else {
        cell.colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }       

    return cell;
}
```

This is all working fine except when I delete a row with `redColor = YES` from the tableview, and I scroll to show rows that was not visible. The first row that becomes visible (first row that reuses the reusable cell) has red color, even though that row is `redColor = NO`. And if I scroll again and hide the cell and then show it again, color is set to clearColor, the way it should be.

I think this is because it's reusing the cell that has just been deleted.
So I'm trying to reset cell's content before reusing.
In `CustomCell.m`

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];

    self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
    self.contentView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
    self.colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

But this is not working.
Apple Doc says

> The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell.

What is the proper way to reset content? Do I have to remove subviews from the superview?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to work.

I remove the cell's contentView when prepareForReuse in `CustomCell.m`

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];

    // Clear contentView
    BOOL hasContentView = [self.subviews containsObject:self.contentView];    
    if (hasContentView) {
        [self.contentView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Add it in again in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Cell
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {        
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    // Restore contentView
    BOOL hasContentView = [cell.subviews containsObject:cell.contentView];
    if (!hasContentView) {
        [cell addSubview:cell.contentView];
    }

    // Configure cell
    MyObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([object.redColor isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]) {
        cell.colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else {
        cell.colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }       

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: isn't this too resource expensive? And it is not "reusable" anymore?

Comment: I am wondering how expensive this will be. If u are computing a lot, you FPS can be dropping significant even below 60.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all cells from reuse cells list then use:

```
[tblView setValue:nil forKey:@"_reusableTableCells"]
```

If you want to remove single cell from reuse cells list then use :

```
NSString* cellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cellID%ld%ld",(long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.row];
        NSMutableDictionary *temp1 = (NSMutableDictionary*)[tblView valueForKey:@"_reusableTableCells"];
        [temp1 removeObjectForKey:cellID];
        [tblView setValue:temp1 forKey:@"_reusableTableCells"];
```

Where cellID is unique reuse cell identifier set while initialising the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tableview delegate method for changing visibility (for example background color) but not data:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: I tried setting the color in the  `willDisplayCell` but it is the same result. It doesn't clear the reused cell's old content...

Comment: Can you try adding  [cell.contentView setNeedsDisplay];
before return Cell;

Comment: hmm, I tried calling `[cell.contentView setNeedsDisplay];` but still not working... I also tried `[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];` but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

```
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CustomCell %ld",(long)indexPath.row];


            CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell = nil;

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


                MyObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                if ([object.redColor isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]) 
                {
                    cell.colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                }


            return cell;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code?? Why do you change the cellIdentifier according to indexpath?? Also setting the cell = nil  before cell == nil doesn't work either..... Thanks for your help though...

Comment: I tried but it crashes the app because cellIdentifier is wrong. And also if I set cell = nil, it makes all the cells blank.

Comment: Hello @TuğrulÖzdemir Plz tell me right way of reusing mechanism.

Comment: actually, not totally killed :) using different cellIdentifier for each row creates new cell for each row. if i have too many row what will happen. i prefer use same identifier for similar rows

Comment: cell = nil;
          if (cell == nil) no sense